# Attempting to upload a different file format to php server

Tags: php, node.js

I'm attempting to upload a file from node js to php an image file works but another file format called "lumi" does not.

The lumi file is basically a json formatted file.

On the js side I have the following:

```
  const filePath = `${desktopDir}/ai2html-output/${individualFile}`;
  const formFileUpload = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    // stream file
    let buff = new Buffer(formFileUpload);
    let base64data = buff.toString('base64');

    form.append('file', base64data);
    form.append('name', individualFile);

  axios.post(API_ENDPOINT, form)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

This uploads a jpg image as a base64 and then in the php side I read it and write to a file like so:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$postData = $_POST['file'];
$postName = $_POST['name'];

 file_put_contents('./data/raws/' . $postName, base64_decode($postData));
```

I then try to execute the same thing for the lumi file with slight variation I don't convert it to a base64.

```
  const filePath = `${desktopDir}/lumi/${fileName}`;
  const formFileUpload = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, { encoding: "utf-8" });

  const lumiForm = new FormData();

      lumiForm.append('file', formFileUpload);
      lumiForm.append('name', fileName);
  
  axios.post(API_ENDPOINT, lumiForm)
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

This displays a 200 with the file name displaying but it does not write to the server.
In this code I check to see if the file name contains "lumi" and then I try to write it.

```
if( strpos($postName, "lumi") !== false ) {
        file_put_contents('./data/lumi-templates/' . $postName, $postData);
        echo $postData;
}
```

No file is posted.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI you can use `fs.readFileSync()` instead of using a promise.

Comment: What does `var_dump(array_keys($_POST));` show? Maybe the file data is being put into `$_FILES`.

Comment: it shows: array(2) {↵  [0]=>↵  string(4) "file"↵  [1]=>↵  string(4) "name"↵}↵{"stages":{"lumise":{"data":{"objects":[null,null,{"type":"text-fx","orig... which the "stages" lumise" etc is the contents of the file. @Barmar

Comment: The part of the output beginning with `{"stages":` looks like the result of `echo $postData;`. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: does the data need to be encoded? Or does php need a specific setting to allow to save a lumi extension file.  Those are my guesses @Barmar

Comment: It's just bytes to PHP, it doesn't care about the file type. Why do you think it's not working if you can see the file in the `echo` output?

Comment: Is the problem just with `file_put_contents()`? Are you sure the filename is what you expect? What does `echo $postName` show?

Comment: yes file_put_contents doesn't put them.  The file name is correct echo $postName would be for example myfile.lumi (which I set in node side) @Barmar

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions problem. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled so you'll see warnings from `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: @Barmar That was it! Permissions problem, as soon as you said that I thought that would be it.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Please check Nginx for allowed file formats, something like below. If you find add lumi as well.

```
location ~*^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|pdf|js|ico|html)
```